# Unknown CMN type 'batch' in pocketsphinx

Tags: android, speech-recognition, cmusphinx, pocketsphinx, pocketsphinx-android

I've read cmusphinx tutorial and ran successfully the pocketsphinx android demo.
Now I want to modify the demo and add support for Italian.
In the Italian model download page ([here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cmusphinx/files/Acoustic%20and%20Language%20Models/Italian/)) I can see two files:

1. cmusphinx-it-5.2.tar.gz: it contains model parameters;
2. it.tar.gz: it contains the dictionary.

I copied dictionary under `/src/main/assets/sync` and create a new folder `/src/main/assets/sync/it-ptm` with the content of **voxforge_it_sphinx.cd_cont_2000** to setup the model.
Then I modified file `assets.lst` by adding the list of italian resources like this:

```
cmudict-en-us.dict
digits.gram
en-phone.dmp
en-us-ptm/README
en-us-ptm/feat.params
en-us-ptm/mdef
en-us-ptm/means
en-us-ptm/noisedict
en-us-ptm/sendump
en-us-ptm/transition_matrices
en-us-ptm/variances
it-ptm/feat.params
it-ptm/feature_transform
it-ptm/mdef
it-ptm/means
it-ptm/mixture_weights
it-ptm/noisedict
it-ptm/transition_matrices
it-ptm/variances
it.dic
menu.gram
weather.dmp
```

Finally I modified the code like this:

```
recognizer = defaultSetup()
            .setAcousticModel(new File(assetsDir, "it-ptm"))
            .setDictionary(new File(assetsDir, "it.dic"))
```

The project build successfully but the application crashes after assets sync. Here the logged error:

*I/cmusphinx: INFO: pocketsphinx.c(145): Parsed model-specific feature parameters from /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/edu.cmu.sphinx.pocketsphinx/files/sync/it-ptm/feat.params
**E/cmusphinx: FATAL: "cmn.c", line 126: Unknown CMN type 'batch'***

Can someone tell me what's wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your pocketsphinx-android files are too old, you need to update them and it should work. You can checkout latest version from github

https://github.com/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx-android-demo

Comment: Thanks Nikolay. To run with the old version I was using **-cmn current** in feat.params instead of -cmn batch, but with the latest version the problem is solved.